# Does a lack of specialization lead to an under-powered character?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In theory, you can play your character any way you want and combine any skills you want to build your character.  But in some games, splitting your focus between too many unrelated skills just leads to a subpar character (e.g. you may be level 10 but because of your mix of skills, you struggle a lot with lvl 10 enemies).

So, if I level up a little bit of everything, will I have issues dealing with enemies later in the game?

Comment: What you've basically said is that a level 10 jack of all trades that could use a sword, a bow, destructive magic, and could conjure skeletons would be weaker than a warrior using a warhammer and heavy armour. The general combination is to specialize in a few things.

Comment: As you have no doubt already noticed, your question was closed. This is because of the subjective nature of your question. Asking which build is more effective is likely to illicit a poll or discussion, which isn't what the site is about. However, your question is definitely salvageable. I see two different ways you can modify your question to fix it, but without removing your core question: 1. Change your question to ask how you make an effective character build. 
2. Change your question to ask if you need to specialize in order to have success in the game, or if it is possible to diversify.

Comment: Fair enough.  I really was asking what combinations will work acceptably well.  I was hoping to avoid experiment with different combinations only to find out that I need to start over to have a character that is good enough for a mediocre player to make it through the game.  Obviously avoiding a jack of all trades is a good idea.  But it's not obvious what combinations outside of core archetypes will have good synergy.  But I get the point of closing it.  C'est la vie.

Answer (score 3):

No, you shouldn't have issues. In fact, you'll probably find the game more playable than you would have if you did specialize in only one thing.

If you have a wide variety of skills, you have answers to anything the enemies could throw at you. No enemy is resistant to everything. You can use magic skills on the warriors and weapons on the mages, taking advantage of everything's weakness. If you only focused in 2-handed weapons, those heavily armored gap-closing enemies would really give you a tough time.

If you level up a bunch of non-combat skills, you're still not going to be in too far over your head. Just make sure you smith up some killer weapons.

Comment: The problem with this is the effectiveness of perks. By splitting your perks at the lower levels of skills, rather than focusing on one or to two trees at a time, you won't have the extremely effective perks. (A thief/mage that wants to use heavy armor will require high level heavy armor perks/sneaking to be effective, which will reduce the effectiveness of magic) It's also extremely important to note the requirements for magicka/stamina/health for some class combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I see how you feel because with my Dark Elf I was being more of an archer and one-handed type when the plus perks were more of magic, and I wasn't sure that my charecter was going to be powerfull. But really you can do anything with your charecter without those more effective perk learning, with just a little more training. This can also alow you to be more broad, alowing to face in different styles to different enemies. 
Thats really all I can say, but combine the answers and I'm pretty sure you'll get a pretty good overall reply.